# How to assign the name to the PHP subarrays

Tags: php, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to generate PHP table with defined subarray names (not sure if I use proper terminology).
Typically I am getting:
Array
but wanted to replace this by:
stdClass Object

With attached code I am able to generate the "standard" array but when I want to have Array replaced by stdClass Object
I am getting results:

```
>>> so with following code:

$testarray = array(
'stdClass Object'=>
      array('title' => 'Hotele - Miejsce',
            'display' => 'hot_miejsce',
            'align' => 'l',
            'width' => 450,
            'order' => 10,
            'format' =>'' ,),
      array('title' => 'Aktualizacja',
            'display' => 'hot_updated',
            'align' => 'c',
            'width' => 200,
            'order' => 20,
            'format' =>'' ,),
);

>>> I get following

[0] : Array
(
    [stdClass Object] => Array
        (
            [title] => Hotele - Miejsce
            [display] => hot_miejsce
            [align] => l
            [width] => 450
            [order] => 10
            [format] => 
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Aktualizacja
            [display] => hot_updated
            [align] => c
            [width] => 200
            [order] => 20
            [format] => 
        )
) 

>>>>> but wanted to get

[0] : Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Hotele - Miejsce
            [display] => hot_miejsce
            [align] => l
            [width] => 450
            [order] => 10
            [format] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Aktualizacja
            [display] => hot_updated
            [align] => c
            [width] => 200
            [order] => 20
            [format] => 
        )

)


>>> so how to modify my original code to get expected result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one line of code will help you on input array,

```
$temp = array_map(function($item){ return (object)$item;}, $testarray);
```

I used type casting to object to every item.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3ll2a).